# JavaScript window.location and JS Frame error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to redirect a page via JavaScript:

```
window.location('http://www.google.com');
```

but in firefox, I'm getting this error:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Cannot convert WrappedNative to function" nsresult: "0x8057000d (NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_CONVERT_WN_TO_FUN)"  location: "JS frame :: [url of my page] :: anonymous :: line 1809"  data: no]

and, well, I have no idea what that means. What's a JS frame? I'm not using any frames on the page itself.

Stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: No problemo. For future reference, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En#Quick_reference) (neé Mozilla Dev Center) is a great resource for this sort of stuff.